# How to guarantee that inout argument won't change Type and won't become nil in a function

Tags: swift, reference, option-type, inout

Working in `swift 4`. I've got a function like this

```
func setFields<T>(_ fromView : UIView,  toObject : inout T!) -> T! 

setFields(self.view, toObject: &self.productExtended.product)

//inside ProductExtended
public var product: Product
```

When i call it like this i get the error:

> "Inout argument could be set to a value with a type other than 'Product'; use a value declared as type '_?' instead"

Moreover if I try to call it for a field inside the ProductExtended.Product i get ambiguous context
Is there a way to guarantee to the compiler that I don't change that argument's value type and i don't make it nil inside the function ?

Comment: Is your second line meant to be `setFields` instead of `getFields`?

Comment: `Like this` is not helpful to answer the question. Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Basically never declare function parameters as implicit unwrapped optional (`!`). If `toObject` must not *become `nil` in a function* declare it as non-optional (remove the exclamation mark). And why has the function an `inout` parameter **and** a return value of the same type?

Comment: This is legacy code, the function is meant to modify the incoming class and also return a reference to it. It uses implicit unwrapped optional because inside there is a lot of Reflection, and if i don't put that i get the type Optional<T> instead of T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inout won't accept **Generic** type , because the reference wants to store value backs to its original value. here is the link for inout https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html